# Connection string was not found

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to run this code:

```
var db = Database.Open("DBNAME");
var q  = "Select Name From Table";

@foreach(var row in db.Query(q)){
      <li> @row.Name </li>
}
```

But I get the error `System.InvalidOperationException: Connection string "DBNAME" was not found.`

So I went in to WebMatrix 3 and added this database under `Other Connections` and working fine in the WebMatrix3 app.  But the connection string I fed WebMatrix to add to the connections was not appended to the web.config file, and I still get this error, so not sure what else to do?  Suggestions?

Also, do DB connections like this have to be closed?  I did not see a close statement in the example I took this from, which is from here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_database.asp

---

Update: I added the following setting in web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DBNAME" connectionString="server=(local)\Server;database=DBNAME;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

And now I get the following error instead: `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.` <-- this error shows up for the `@foreach` line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add the connection string to your web.config file. Depending on what kind of database you use.

If you use SQL Server you can use something like this:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBNAME" connectionString="Data Source=.\Server;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=Username;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
<configuration>
```

More on connection strings here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Edit:

Yes Database connection should be closed! It implements IDisposable interface so you should use the using clause.

Here is an example

```
using (Database db = Database.Open("DBNAME"))
{
   // Do your database stuff here
}
```

It will call the Dispose mehtod when it reaches the end of using clause. Dispose() will close the connection upon many other things.

Comment: I did this and I get a new error now, please see the edit in the OP.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Your connectionString is in MySql format, try the one I made.

Comment: Awesome it works, thank you.  I just have a question about the connection string being stored in web.config -- Shouldn't it be saved encrypted?  Also, can you please address the other question in the OP about if closing of the connection is needed and how it's done?  Thank you!

Comment: If this is the answer that helped you you should consider accepting it

Comment: @TopinFrassi Well it did not yet address the concern about closing the connection, which was in the OP. Thank you.

Comment: Added answer to second question

Comment: Thanks, but why use `Dispose()` and not `Close()`?

Comment: Using clause will use Dispose() automatically upon reaching the end bracket. Dispose() is intented for releasing resources that are heavy on the program like streams and database connections.Close will only close the connection and not release the resources thus the same instance can be reopened.